# CSimpleSocket failing after client disconnects

Tags: php, c++, sockets

I'm having some problems with sockets in c++(server) and php(client). Below is the code. The problem is that whenever the client gets disconnected (because of failure or whatever) the pClient->send() function should return -1 or 0. However, it doesn't. Therefore I cannot break the loop, and the program fails on this function. What am I doing wrong? I hope you can help me!

```
int sentSucces=0;
char szData[MAX_PACKET];
memset(szData, 0, MAX_PACKET);

CPassiveSocket socket;
CActiveSocket *pClient = NULL;
sendInterval = 10;
socket.Initialize();
socket.Listen((const uint8 *) "127.0.0.1", 9876);
socket.SetNonblocking(); //if no connection in queue, don't wait (accept())

while (1) {
    //check queue for connections.
    if ((pClient = socket.Accept()) != NULL) {
        pClient->SetNonblocking();
        cout << "++ connected\n";
        while (1) {
            // Receive request from the client.
            cout << "- receiving....\n";
            if (pClient->Receive(MAX_PACKET) > 0) {
                cout << "-- received\n";
                strncpy(szData, (const char *) pClient->GetData(), pClient->GetBytesReceived());
                cout << "-- +: " << szData << "\n";
                //clear memory of szData
                memset(szData, 0, MAX_PACKET);

            } else {
                cout << "-- NOT received\n";
            }

            string bericht = "hallo";
            cout << "sending....\n";
            sentSucces = pClient->Send((const uint8 *) bericht.c_str(), strlen(bericht.c_str()));
            cout << "++ send:" << sentSucces << "\n";
            if (sentSucces < 1) break;
            sleep(4);
        }
        cout << "++ disconnecting...\n";
        pClient->Close();
        cout << "++ disconnected\n";
    } else {
        //  cout << "++ no connections\n";
    }
    usleep(10000);
}
```

Comment: What protocol are you implementing over TCP? How does the protocol specification say the client should detect the disconnection of the server? (If you haven't documented your protocol, that's your problem. Until you are a TCP expert, you have to document every protocol you implement or you'll constantly run into cases where you have no idea what you should do and none of your code works with any other part of your code.) Also, why don't you handle any error cases in the `Receive` code path?

Answer (score 1):

Your code waits forever in `Receive`. If you don't want to do that, don't. The reason the `Send` function won't return an error is because you never get to it, waiting forever in `Receive`.

Whatever protocol you are implementing, does its specification say this end of the connection should wait forever try to receive data? If so, it's broken. If not, then your code is broken. If you don't have a protocol specification, you need to write one. Otherwise, all your code will only work together by luck.

The TCP protocol does guarantee that a side that sends will eventually detect a disconnection. But it makes no such guaranteed for a side that waits forever to receive data. If the other side never sends anything at all and goes away, you'll still be waiting forever. When you design a protocol that works over TCP, you must take this into account in the protocol design. This should have been resolved before even a single line of code was written.

Comment: pClient is set to non blocking, so it doesn't wait in receive. I can see that, because before the crash it prints "sending...".

Comment: Ah, well then your code will spin for a few minutes but it should eventually fail when the send times out. How long have you waited?

Comment: It fails almost directly after the client disconnects.

Comment: What do you mean by "fails"? What exactly happens?

Comment: It prints: "sending..." as a last line. Than the program stops. No more output, no error message even. The cout right behind Send() is not printed anymore.

Comment: If you're using the library I think you're using, this version of of `Send` is only for datagrams. [Note: This function is used only for a socket of type CSimpleSocket::SocketTypeUdp](http://sockets.carrierlabs.com/classCPassiveSocket.html#cd8c5d043b7220ee3ca2c6d15c5dfe88)

Comment: I also tried using CSimpleSocket::Send(const struct iovec * sendVector,int32 nNumItems), but than the same happens.